# Is there an easy way to move user data between 2 sites?

Tags: 7, drush

I am totally new in Drupal, and I am using Drupal 7. I was asked to move data between two sites that don't even have the same structure, and have different fields.

Can anything bei done with a tool like Drush, or with MySQL?

Comment: I'll save you the time and say no, that this is not possible with existing tools. You would have to employ the use of the Migrate Framework to transpose data from one source to the other and into the fields you want.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what type of Data?

Comment: That would be just user input through webforms, like "name, "address"...

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use views to output the data you want into a csv file (with views data export module) and then import the data into the destination site using Feeds module. This technique has worked well for me on a number of occasions.

Additionally, you could try the Features module but this is quite complicated and may be difficult to get your head around initially.

Answer (score 0):

Did table download from the old webforms, corrected all field keys and filtered data into a new CSV file, and through "Upload" in the new webform.  Not sure why it only accepted 11 rows at a time, but got all transferred.  Final tunig was done direct in MySQL database.